# Where in create-react-app can you set the version of Node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, create-react-app, nvm

I'm experiencing a bug in my code when running `docker compose up` to containerize my react-flask web app. The bug is mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11565) with everyone saying to downgrade to stable version 16 of Node.

I installed version 16 of node on my system (checking it using `node -v` and I have v16.8.0 my virtual environment and globally v15.8.0).

The app is also running without this error when I use Flask development server / gunicorn and is just happening when I run Docker compose.

However, it seems that as soon as **react-scripts start** is run by Docker Compose, I get the error:

```
Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in /app/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/package.json
```

as documented in linked issue above.
At the bottom of this error message is this:
**Node.js v17.4.0**

I've looked in my project folders and I can't work out where it's grabbing/setting Node to the newest version. So I first wondered if each version of create-react-app might ship with a specific version of node, or pick up the current version of node on your system when you first create the react app using it. How can I downgrade it to 16 such that react-scripts doesn't default to 17.4.0? I created the app almost a year ago, so I couldn't have had 17.4.0 at that point (it's only just been released).

Appreciate any help in fixing this.

Comment: Node isn’t shipped via CRA. You are using 17 somehow, maybe with double installation from brew and nvm.

Comment: does node-v only show nvm versions?

Comment: Actually it seems that you’re using docker-compose for this. Your image must be using node:latest which defaults to 17 currently.

Comment: It's using FROM node:alpine. Would this amount to the equivalent?

Comment: Node versions are listed here. If you’re using a Dockerfile, update the FROM statement to node:16. https://hub.docker.com/_/node node:alpine or non-version specifics will be published with 17.

Comment: Thank you SO much OFRBG. The project is running!!!!!!